# RoR: How to define a method for a partial?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, partials

I am trying to render a partial on a page...like so

```
../devise/sessions/new.html.erb

<%= render partial: '/tweets/latest_tweets' %>
```

All good

In the partial I would like to do "each do" like so...

```
../tweets/_latest_tweets.html.erb

<% @tweets.each do |tweet| %>
 <%= tweet.content %>
<% end %>
```

I get undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

How do I define this method for my partial in my tweets controller?

I have index like so

```
tweets_controller.rb

    def index
        @tweets = Tweet.all
    end
```

Which is fine for the index but I don't know how to do same for my partial (I tried just defining my partial like the index but that did not seem to work)

Anyone have a solution I could try?

ty

Comment: Have you get @tweets in file **devise/sessions/new.html.erb**? Can you check this by using debugger or binding.pry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the collection when rendering the partial. It'll give something like this:

**devise/sessions/new.html.erb**

```
<%= render partial: 'tweets/latest_tweets', collection: @tweets, as: :tweet %>
```

**tweets/_latest_tweets.html.erb**

```
<%= tweet.content %>
```

Just like that, and it will iterate through your collection automatically.

Fore more info, please read [Rails - Layout and Rendering](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html)

Comment: What is the content of @tweets? Did you verify that there are tweets in the db?

Comment: yup, plenty of tweets but not showing. I have "authenticate user!" on the index controller - might have something to do with?

Comment: Strange, it's not rendering the partial at all, nothing to do with the loop

Comment: @davidm Ok I understood why! You are populating `@tweets` in TweetsController#index but you are trying to render them in Devise::SessionsController#new. If you want the tweets to be rendered in that view you need to override the #new method from Devise::SessionsController to populate `@tweets`

Comment: Thanks. I'm thinking of doing this in reverse. Setting up a new page and having the login form embedded in that page instead might save a lot of aggravation!